# Calling a select method from main program and filling listbox

Tags: c#, mysql, xaml

My XAML application currently calls a `dbObject.Select();` method that then runs a SQL select statement.

The difficulty I am now facing right now is outputting this information into `DriverListBox`, a listbox field that I have on the UI. How do I do this from MainWindow?

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dbObject = new DbConnect();
        dbObject.OpenConnection();
        dbObject.Select();
    }
```

**DbConnect.cs**

```
    public List<string>[] Select()
    {
        const string query = "SELECT * from rent";

        // Create a list to store the result
        var list = new List<string>[4];
        list[0] = new List<string>();
        list[1] = new List<string>();
        list[2] = new List<string>();
        list[3] = new List<string>();

        // Create command
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read the data and store it in a list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader["dNo"] + "");
            list[1].Add(dataReader["pDate"] + "");
            list[2].Add(dataReader["pRent"] + "");
            list[3].Add(dataReader["status"] + "");
        }

        // Close
        dataReader.Close();
        CloseConnection();

        // Return list
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is not to select into a bunch of `List<String>`, but to select into a DTO (**D** ata **T** ransfer **O** bject). You then hold a list of these:

```
    DatabaseObjects = new List<MyDataObject>();

    // Create command
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Read the data and store it in a list
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        MyDataObject newRow = new MyDataObject();
        newRow.No = (dataReader["dNo"] + "");
        newRow.Date = (dataReader["pDate"] + "");
        newRow.Rent = (dataReader["pRent"] + "");
        newRow.Status = (dataReader["status"] + "");
        list.Add(newRow);
    }
```

You then use this list as the `ItemsSource` (bound) of your `ListBox` with an `ItemTemplate` that determines how all the data is shown. Normally this would be done by an `ObservableCollection` rather than a `List`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseObjects}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding No}"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date"/>
               ...
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Hi Bradley, thanks for your response. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365325.aspx - this article insinuates that DatabaseObjects can only be used in SQL Server instances, I am connecting to a MySQL database (XAMPP), does it still apply?

Comment: @methuselah DTO are a general concept. Getting an *auto-mapper* is more difficult going to other RDBMS, but in this case, you can do it yourself.